# What does inplace_merge do if the ranges are not sorted?

Tags: c++, stl

The [documentation to inplace_merge](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/inplace_merge) says that "the ranges must be sorted". But, it does not say what happens if the ranges are not sorted. I tried to use it with unsorted ranges, and the result is an unsorted array, but this may be compiler-dependent. What can I conclude from the lack of documentation about this case - does it mean that, if the ranges are unsorted, the result is [undefined behavior](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2olsGf6JIkU&t=240s)?
(for example: is a standards-compliant compiler allowed to create a segmentation fault in case the ranges are not sorted?)

Comment: It's the same as any function with preconditions. If you do not meet the preconditions, who can say what the function will do? E.g. if you pass an unsorted range to binary_search, what will happen? It's probably not going to be language-level undefined behavior, but the result is definitely not defined.

Comment: FWIW, [here is what the standard says](http://eel.is/c++draft/alg.merge#8), which isn't any more informative. Based on that, I would expect calling `inplace_merge` with unsorted ranges to be implicitly Undefined Behavior

Comment: At the risk of being Captain Obvious: *Undefined behaviour* is something that the standard doesn't define (hence, undefined). If there were documentation about how it should behave, it will no longer be *undefined*. Why? Because this gives the freedom to the implementer to do the best algorithm without worrying for you violating the API's contract.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`inplace_merge` requires the inputs to be sorted, which is specified in [[alg.merge]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/alg.merge#7):

> Requires: *[first, middle)* and *[middle, last)* shall be valid ranges *sorted* with respect to `comp` and `proj`.

So strictly speaking supplying unsorted input to `inplace_merge` is [*undefined behavior*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/intro.compliance#2.3), end of story.

But the standard also requires it to be stable and [O(N) complexity](http://eel.is/c++draft/alg.merge#11).

Which brings us to the only possible implementation, using a [two-pointer algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-two-sorted-arrays/): traverse both ranges simultaneously, "zipping" them together by selecting the smallest elements from both at each step.

In practice therefore it will most probably execute to completion, with an unsorted result.

Comment: There's a good chance that some implementations assert that the input is sorted in debug configurations.